# Why are my python functions being called twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python and whenever I run my script, the first two functions `humanPlay()` and `computerPlay()` are called twice. I do not want this.

I noticed when I comment out the draw variable within the `setRules()` function, the program works properly. I'm not sure why `f"{computerPlay()}"` and `f"{humanPlay()}"` are not printing the returned value instead.

I also verified that the py file is not named `Random` to prevent the module from importing itself.

```
import random


Player = "Player"
Computer = "Computer"
options = ["ROCK","PAPER","SCISSORS"]

def main():
    def humanPlay():
        response = input("Make a selection between Rock, Paper, Scissors: ", )
        response.upper()

        if response.upper() in options:
            print(response.upper())
            return response.upper()
        else:
            print(f"{response.upper()}, is not a valid selection")
            return humanPlay()

    def computerPlay():
         print(random.choice(options))
         return random.choice(options)

    def setRules():
        rockWin = "You Win! ROCK beats SCISSORS "
        paperWin = "You Win! PAPER beats ROCK "
        scissorsWin = "You Win! SCISSORS beats PAPER "
        draw = print("It's a Draw!, computer selected", f"{computerPlay()}", "and you selected", f"{humanPlay()}")
        #loser = print(f"You Lose! {humanPlay()}", f"can't beat {computerPlay()}")


    humanPlay()
    computerPlay()
    setRules()

main()
```

Ideally the draw variable should equal something similar to the following:

```
It's a Draw!, computer selected ROCK and you selected ROCK
```

Note: I still have to write the logic for the program to know the difference between a Rock, Paper and scissor.

For now I just want the proper values to be returned and not the entire functions.

Comment: They run twice, because they're called twice.  You call `humanPlay` and `computerPlay` at the bottom of `main` and call them again in `setRules`.

Comment: You call `humanPlay()` and `computerPlay()`, then call `setRules()` which itself calls those two functions.  You need to call them *once*, saving their results in variables, and pass those variables to `setRules()` so that it can use them.

Comment: `f"{computerPlay()}"` and `f"{humanPlay()}"` call the functions. I assume that's not what you want, but the solution is not totally clear. Please make a [mre].

Comment: BTW, calling `random.choice(options)` twice makes *two different* choices, you know that, right?

Comment: Also `print` always returns `None`, so `draw` will always be `None`.

Comment: `main` is not structured correctly.  The 3 functionS do not belong inside `main`. Each of the three functions should do something, they should be called from within `main`, but not reside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As noted in the comments, the functions are called twice within `main`

  - Once at the bottom of `main`
  - Once in `setRules`
- The functions should not reside in `main`
- The functions should be called from `main`, and the value `returned`, stored as a variable to use in `setRules`
- The logic is not set to determine the winner between `rock`, `paper` or `scissor`
- The effective [scope of](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python)  `Player`, `Computer` and `options` is global.

```py
def humanPlay() -> str:
    response = input("Make a selection between Rock, Paper, Scissors: ", )
    response = response.upper()

    if response in options:
        print(response)
        return response
    else:
        print(f"{response}, is not a valid selection")
        return humanPlay()

def computerPlay() -> str:
    comp_choice = random.choice(options)
    print(comp_choice)
    return comp_choice

def setRules(comp_choice: str, human_choice: str):
    rockWin = "You Win! ROCK beats SCISSORS "
    paperWin = "You Win! PAPER beats ROCK "
    scissorsWin = "You Win! SCISSORS beats PAPER "
    draw = print("It's a Draw!, computer selected", f"{comp_choice}", "and you selected", f"{human_choice}")
    #loser = print(f"You Lose! {human_choice}", f"can't beat {comp_choice}")

Player = "Player"
Computer = "Computer"
options = ["ROCK","PAPER","SCISSORS"]

def main():

    h_choice = humanPlay()
    c_choice = computerPlay()

    setRules(c_choice, h_choice)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your interpretation of the f-string interpolation and in general of function calling.

When you have `some_func()` this will call the function (i.e. the code therein will be executed).

The f-string interpolation works that whatever is inside it, it will be executed and its result will be converted to string.

Therefore, to fix (this aspect of) your code, you should collect the result of `humanPlay()` and `computerPlay()` into some variable, e.g. `human_move = humanPlay()` and then pass that value to `setRules()` (also making sure that `setRules()` actually accept such value).

Answer (score -1):

The reason your are seeing `humanPlay()` and `computerPlay()` called twice, is because you are!
When you print them in setRules:
`draw = print("It's a Draw!, computer selected", f"{computerPlay()}", "and you selected", f"{humanPlay()}")`
You are not getting the previous result but calling them again.

I would assign the return values of humanPlay and computerPlay to some varaibles and pass that into setRules.

i.e.

```
import random


Player = "Player"
Computer = "Computer"
options = ["ROCK","PAPER","SCISSORS"]

def main():
    def humanPlay():
        response = input("Make a selection between Rock, Paper, Scissors: ", )
        response.upper()

        if response.upper() in options:
            print(response.upper())
            return response.upper()
        else:
            print(f"{response.upper()}, is not a valid selection")
            return humanPlay()

    def computerPlay():
         choice = random.choice(options)
         return choice

    def setRules(humanResult, computerResult):
        rockWin = "You Win! ROCK beats SCISSORS "
        paperWin = "You Win! PAPER beats ROCK "
        scissorsWin = "You Win! SCISSORS beats PAPER "
        print("It's a Draw!, computer selected", f"{computerResult}", "and you selected", f"{humanResult}")
        #loser = print(f"You Lose! {humanResult}", f"can't beat {computerResult}")


    hResult = humanPlay()
    cResult = computerPlay()
    setRules(hResult, cResult)

main()
```